# Extended BNF to BNF translation

Tags: bison, bnf, ebnf

I have this grammar in EBNF notation:

```
expr -> expr (opt1 | opt2 | opt3) expr
```

And i want to convert it to BNF to use it in Bison but i get shift/reduce errors in this:

```
expr : expr opt1 expr | expr opt2 expr | expr opt3 expr
```

I guess i misunderstood something along the way. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
expr: expr optexpr expr
optexpr: opt1 | opt2 | opt3
```

The shift/reduce erros are due to the overlapping expr prefixes.  By introducing another definition, the parsing of expr becomes unambiguous.